# Adicionar novos campos na migration ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá estou trabalhando com Ruby On Rails, e para autenticação da plataforma estou utilizando a gem 'devise'. Me deparei com uma situação onde eu preciso adicionar novos campos para cadastro do usuário (Data de aniversário, gênero, etc...) e o device só me disponibiliza os recursos básicos (email, password). Para adicionar esses campos que eu preciso basta colocar dentro da migration ou preciso fazer algum passo a mais ?

Parte do código gerado pelo devise:

`def change
    create_table :members do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ''
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ''`

Para adicionar novos campos basta fazer isso ?

`def change
    create_table :members do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ''
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ''
      t.string :MEU_NOVO_CAMPO, null: true, default: ''`

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Além de gerar uma migration com os novos campos

```
rails g migration AddNewFieldsToMembers
```

Que irá criar a migrate

```
class AddNewFieldsToMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :members, :field_name, :type
  end
end
```

Você ainda vai ter que criar os controller do devise

```
rails g devise:controller user
```

Que irá criar uma pasta com os controllers de user.
Nesses controllers você irá ter que adicionar os campos em alguns métodos para dar permissão de acesso.

Maiores informações https://github.com/plataformatec/devise procure sobre custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o caminho é gerar outra migration que irá adicionar os novos campos.
Algo como:

```
rails g migration AddNewFieldsToMembers

class AddNewFieldsToMembers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :members, :field_name, :type
  end
end
```

Aqui você pode ver a lista dos tipos disponíveis pra versão do Rails e banco de dados específicos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918117/rails-4-list-of-available-datatypes